# c++ setting up for sqlite3

Tags: c++, c, windows, sqlite, compiler-construction

I've downloaded the source code for sqlite3 to start programming with the sqlite3 interface in c++. but I don't know how to get the .lib file for sqlite 3.

I have these files:

sqlite3.c
shell.c
sqlite3.h
sqlite3ext.h

and this is my simple source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SQL/sqlite3.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
    sqlite3 * db;

    int rc = sqlite3_open("file.txt", &db);

}
```

but i get "undefined reference to sqlite3_open"

this is in my makefile:

```
MY_LIBS = -lsqlite3
main:
    g++ -g main.cpp -o sqliteex
```

which doesn't compile because there is no library named sqlite3.lib

where do I get this file or how do I build it so I can start using sqlite3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your build command to

```
gcc -g -c sqlite3.c -o sqlite3.o
g++ -g -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -o sqliteex sqlite3.o main.o
```

(I assume sqlite3.c is the "amalgamation.")

This is their recommended way of including sqlite in your project; you compile it right in instead of linking to it.

You may (i'm not sure, you'll have to test this) need to put the sqlite include in an

```
extern "C" {}
```

block.

Comment: Tried it, it sent an enormous string of errors to the prompt at compile time.  Maybe something isn't set up with my compiler correctly?

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to use a c compiler for sqlite. Try it now.